# Image_Processing - MiniMagic - Shrine different quality for every derivatives

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, minimagick, shrine

Is there some way to set different quality for every created image? **And of course leave original file with quality 88**

> image_uploader.rb

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

class ImageUploader < Shrine

    Attacher.derivatives do |original|
        magick = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original).saver(quality: 88)
        # generate the thumbnails you want here 
        { 
          thumb:  magick.resize_to_fill!(150, 150), /// quality 50
          medium: magick.resize_to_fill!(500, 500), /// quality 50
          large:  magick.resize_to_limit!(800, 800), /// quality 88
        }
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use saver to pass quality, like that:

```
{ 
  thumb:  magick.saver(quality: 50).resize_to_fill!(150, 150),
  medium: magick.saver(quality: 50).resize_to_fill!(500, 500),
  large:  magick.saver(quality: 88).resize_to_limit!(800, 800),
}
```